# Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct CV.experience storage ref

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I hope you're doing well! actually, I'm trying to create a smart contract containing a map of struct I want to store the new experiences in a mapping in which the key is an address I've got in the parameter of the function but unfortunately, I don't know what is precisely the problem when this error appears:

from solidity: TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct CV.experience storage ref. --> contracts/experience.sol:19:9:
experiences[_addressCompagnie].push(

the code is :

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract CV {
    struct experience {
        address addressCompagnie;
        string nomCompagnie;
        string titrePoste;
        string description;
        bool valide;
    }
    mapping(address => experience ) experiences ; 
    function addExperience(
        address _addressCompagnie,
        string memory _nomCompagnie,
        string memory _titrePoste,
        string memory _description
    ) public { 
        experiences[_addressCompagnie].push(
            experience(
                _addressCompagnie,
                _nomCompagnie,
                _titrePoste,
                _description,
                false
            )
        );
    }
}'''

thanks for helping me !
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping value is of type `experience`, not `experience[]` (an array), so you can't `push()` into it.

Depending on your use case, you can assign the single value without pushing

```
mapping(address => experience) experiences;

function addExperience(...) public {
    // set the single value
    experiences[_addressCompagnie] = experience(...);
}
```

or to change the mapping definition to `experience[]` (an array of `experience`) and then push into it.

```
mapping(address => experience[]) experiences;

function addExperience(...) public {
    // push into the array
    experiences[_addressCompagnie].push(experience(...));
}
```